# Android Turn-by-Turn API?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

Android 2.0 has [turn-by-turn directions](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/blog/2009/oct/28/google-sat-nav-android), however, I do not yet see an API exposed for this in the 2.0 SDK.  Are there any documented plans to expose an API for calling into the new turn-by-turn features?

Comment: Is it going to be part of Android 2.0 or merely an application built on top of it? I'd think the later, so no API - at least not as part of the SDK.

Answer (score 7):

I will be rather surprised if there is an API for this.

Bear in mind that Google licenses much of this data from TeleAtlas. It is one thing for Google to license it for its own use, and that probably was not cheap. It is quite another thing for Google to license it on behalf of arbitrary third-party developers. This is one of the reasons why the Google Maps API for Android terms and conditions states that you cannot:

> 8.7.  use the Service or Content with any products, systems, or applications
>   for or in connection with (a) real
>   time navigation or route guidance
>   based on position input from a sensor
>   (including but not limited to any
>   visual or audible turn-by-turn route
>   guidance); or (b) any systems or
>   functions for automatic or autonomous
>   control of vehicle behavior; or (c)
>   dispatch, fleet management, business
>   asset tracking, or similar enterprise
>   applications (for avoidance of doubt,
>   you are permitted to use the Service
>   to create Maps API Implementations to
>   track people or assets equipped with a
>   sensor, where the tracking of the
>   people or assets is not critical to
>   the core business or service of the
>   application user.  For example, you
>   are permitted to use the Maps APIs to
>   create "Friend Finder" applications
>   that allow consumers to track the
>   locations of their friends? mobile
>   devices, but you are not permitted to
>   use the Maps APIs to create "Business
>   Asset Tracking" applications that
>   track or locate business or government
>   users? field sales or field service
>   personnel, vehicles or other assets
>   that are critical (not incidental) to
>   the core business or service of the
>   application user);

I am fairly certain the above clause is there for TeleAtlas' benefit.

Now, if Google amasses enough independent data to do turn-by-turn navigation, then perhaps I can see an API for it, but not until then.

Comment: Actually, I may now be wrong about the source of the data. In  http://www.mondaynote.com/2009/11/01/the-meaning-of-droid/ I see: "Keen observers noted Google no longer refers to an external source for map data; previously, it used TeleAtlas, owned by TomTom." If true for turn-by-turn directions, that would seem to make APIs more likely. However, you might see them on the Web first -- don't assume they'll be on Android first.

Comment: i was wondering if you have an updated answer on this subject? Been looking around and cant find anything. Its been almost 4 years i would imagine there should be something right?