# How to display route information between two points in Android?

Tags: android, navigation

I am able to show the route between two geo points in android using google map. Now i want to know how to guide the user like turn right, take left; likewise should display message. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no turn-by-turn api (yet). See also [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659396/android-turn-by-turn-api)

Comment: Hi Maurits, thanx for ur response.Sorry actually i m expecting Driving direction information.Can u please tell me how to get the Driving direction information in andorid?If you can provide me some code snippet.

Comment: Hi Kumar. That is exactly the problem. There are no API calls in Android 2.x to get driving directions.

Comment: Oh...Is that API call is available in Android 1.5? and I m using the Android 1.5 SDK only.

Comment: Nope, it's not available in any of the current Android versions.