# Give route and time of Api Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I wonder if with the Google Maps API I can trace a route between two points, taking the distance and time to go, as well as Maps Android application, if anyone has an example of how to do, I am grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link: [Android google maps APIs get directions programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642438/android-google-maps-apis-get-directions-programming)

There are no official android API for google maps routing. If you want that, you should download the path from google maps web service and draw the path (polygon) manually.